# How can I adjust the mouse scrollwheel speed?

Tags: settings, system, desktop, mouse, pantheon

Does anyone know how to make the mouse scrollwheel go faster?

Answer (score 13):

## Adjust scroll speed

This is based directly on an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/621140/413066) to a [similar question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285689/increase-mouse-wheel-scroll-speed/621140#621140) by user [stvn66](https://askubuntu.com/users/385212/stvn66). I have tested it under **elementary OS 0.4 Loki**.

Unfortunately there is no simple setting to adjust scrolling speed right now, which seems to be a problem for many Linux based operating systems, not only elementary OS.

Currently the best option is to install `imwheel`, for example by typing the following in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install imwheel
```

then create the file `~/.imwheelrc` containing:

```
".*"
None,      Up,   Button4, 5
None,      Down, Button5, 5
Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
Shift_L,   Up,   Shift_L|Button4
Shift_L,   Down, Shift_L|Button5
```

where you should try different values for `#` in the lines 2–3:

```
None,      Up,   Button4, #
None,      Up,   Button5, #
```

Then stop and restart imwheel to test the settings by using the commands:

```
killall imwheel
imwheel -b "4 5"
```

Please note that at least for me this does increase the scrolling speed of the scroll wheel *and* the touchpad.

If everything works as expected, you can add this tool to start automatically once you log in. Go to System Settings → Applications → Startup, click the "+" button in the bottom left, type in `imwheel -b "4 5"` and submit by pressing enter.

Comment: This is great but horizontal scrolling by holding shift is still slow. How to speed that up @quassy?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no setting in elementary OS to adjust this. There is a bug over there at [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-mouse-touchpad/+bug/1213473). A possible solution could be http://www.webupd8.org/2015/12/how-to-change-mouse-scroll-wheel-speed.html (I have not tried it).